# Trying to pass a PHP variable to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

I have a JavaScript popup that will allow you to send a message to another user. I'm not using a form because I want the users to be able to send messages while staying on their current page. So what I'm doing is echo'ing out the PHP variable to the call function and then it gets sent off when the user hits the send button (id=mbutton)

When I go over to the JavaScript function and alert out the passed variable, it alerts fine right off the bat but goes to "undefined" after passed through an if statement.

As you can see from the code below, I have 2 alerts setup...as I said, the first alerts fine but the second one does not. Could anyone explain to me why this is happening?

```
<div id="msgcont">
    <div id="msgheader">
        <span>Send a Message to <? if($array['login']!=$c_log['login']) { echo 
$array['login']; } ?> - Remember to be curtious! </span>
    </div>
    <div id="msgclose" onMouseDown="butclick('message', 'submit')"><span>X</span></div>
    <textarea id="msg"></textarea>
    <div id="mbutton" onMouseUP="butclick('send', 'submit', '<? 
if($array['login']!=$c_log) { echo $array['login']; } ?>')" 
onMouseDown="butclick('send', 'down')">Send</div>
</div>

function butclick(but, action, sentFrom) {
    alert(sentFrom);
    if(but=='send') { 
        alert(sentFrom);
        x = document.getElementById('msg').value;
        if(x==null || x=="") { alert("Please Enter your message before attemping to 
send"); } else { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this statement here appears to be incorrect:

```
if($array['login']!=$c_log) { echo $array['login']; } ?>')"
```

Whereas, you are comparing `$array['login']!=$c_log` but only a few lines before you are comparing: `$array['login']!=$c_log['login']`.

This leads me to believe that `$c_log` as an array, and compaing `$array['login']` (a string) to `$c_log` (an array) will always conflict.

Comment: you're correct, that was a typo. the line actually is $array['login']!=$c_log['login']

Comment: that was not the problem though. I just figured it out. I moved the function call from onMouseDown to onMouseUp and for some reason that fixed the issue, not sure exactly WHY or HOW that fixed it...but it did.

Comment: please answer your own question to help future users.

Comment: I want to, but it says I can't answer my own question until 8 hour have passed since I am a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I'm not sure WHY this is happening but I figured out how to get it working. If you look at the code below I have both onMouseUP and onMouseDown...I moved my butclick function call from onMouseDown to onMouseUP and it seems to be working just fine....don't ask me to explain it...it just is.

```
<div id="mbutton" onMouseUP="butclick('send', 'submit', '<? if($array['login']!=$c_log) { 
echo $array['login']; } ?>')" onMouseDown="butclick('send', 'down')">Send</div>
```